# Text area bug in Firefox 4

Tags: support, design, firefox

On Stack Overflow (and lots of other websites too, unfortunately), Firefox 4 beta (at least versions 4.0b4pre-b6pre) automatically adds a resize handle to text areas, which is probably not what you would want it to do, and it is a bit annoying to have when it obviously shouldn't be there.

[image: Screenshot]

This is most likely because the `resize` CSS property for text areas is set to `both` by default in HTML text areas in Firefox 4 beta, instead of `none`, like most other browsers.

Comment: I like the resize handle.  What is the peril in leaving it there?

Comment: I've always had that resize handle in Safari. Love it, and it's not giving me any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handle is in Chrome as well, I like it and I use it.

The only bug iIencounter with it is moving it under a question's hyperlink on the right of the page, but that is equally a user error.

If it ain't broke, Don't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Betas are not officially supported.

Comment: Though true, that's not really the issue here.